# Distribution of solution to linear SDE

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a linear SDE of the form:

$$dX_t = \alpha X_tdt + \beta dW_t,\\ X_t = x$$
I would like to determine an explicit solution, as well as that solution's distribution if possible.

My issue with the first task is that we are given $X_t = x$, and not, as usual, $X_0 = x$. With regards to the second task, I do believe such solutions will be .... normal? Log-normal?

EDIT: I found the solution to the first question, but only for $X_0 = x$. So I am wondering, do we just replace $t$ in the formula with $T-t$?

Comment: Avoid writing $dX_t$ and $X_t$ with the same subscript, that is causing confusion. And you could write it as $T-t$ sure, note that in this example the drift and diffusion coefficients do not depend on time, and therefore this problem is equivalent to solving up to time $S = T - t$ the SDE with $X_0 = x$.

Comment: So you would say the solution is $exp( \alpha (T-t)) + \int_0^{T-t} exp( \alpha (T - t - s)) \beta dW_s$? Seems a but clunky.

Comment: It does look clunky! My point was to, as you first suggested, replace any mention of $T-t $ with $S $ and solve from $s=0$

Answer (score 1):

We follow [Integrating factor and homogeneous equation for SDEs.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4444106/integrating-factor-and-homogeneous-equation-for-sdes), but write the details for this specific case
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}X_t = a(t)X_t \mathrm{d}t +  d(t)\mathrm{d}B_t. 
\end{align*}

We start with integrating factor

$$Y_t=\exp\left(\int_0^t a(s)ds\right).$$
For $Z_t:=X_tY_t^{-1}$ we use the product rule to get
\begin{align}
dZ_t=& X_t d(Y_t^{-1})+Y^{-1}dX_t+d\langle X, Y^{-1}\rangle_t\\
&= \frac{-X_t}{Y_t}a(t)dt+\frac{1}{Y_t}\big[a(t)X_t dt + d(t)dB_t\big]\\
&= d(t)Y_t^{-1}dB_t.
\end{align}

Now integrate to obtain

$$Z_t=X_0\int_0^t d(s)Y_s^{-1}dB_s,$$

and so

$$X_t=Y_t\left(X_0\int_0^t d(s)Y_s^{-1}dB_s\right)$$

$$=\exp\left(\int_0^t a(s)ds\right).\left(X_0\int_0^t d(s)\exp\left(-\int_0^t a(s)ds\right).dB_s\right)$$